# Isn't \d redundant in [\w\d]?

Tags: python, regex

I am reading a book and see tons of examples like this:

```
(?P<email>
[\w\d.+-]+ # username
@
([\w\d.]+\.)+ # domain name prefix
(com|org|edu) # limit the allowed top-level domains
)
```

Since `\w` means `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`, `\d` means `[0-9]`, `\d` is subset of `\w`.
So, aren't those "\d"s redundant? Please someone confirm my understanding is correct as this drives me nut.

Comment: Perhaps they're specifically looking for words that *end* with a number, i.e. smith7 or jones5.

Comment: @JohnGordon if that was the case they would have the `\d` token outside of the grouping, not inside.

Comment: this suggests it's a pointless exercise in any case: http://davidcel.is/posts/stop-validating-email-addresses-with-regex/

Comment: @davejagoda Good article. Shame it gets ruined a bit by using the moronic jwz quote in the introduction. And the `EmailAddressValidator` is actually quite nice, presumably RFC compliant (I haven’t checked) *and* readable (I challenge anyone to write a better parser without using regex). But yeah, the real solution is to not validate an email address based on syntax.

Comment: Yes it is. <°))))))))))))))>

Comment: @davejagoda: "The activation email is a practice..." is the important thing in this article, but "Sections 3.2.4 and 3.4.1 of the RFC go into ..." is a totally false argument.

Comment: Thank you everyone, I feel much better now.

Comment: @JohnGordon no, if that's the case, it would be `[\w.+-]+\d` or `[\w.+-]+\d$`

Comment: @KonradRudolph - The famous jwz quote is far from moronic. Regular expressions are a good solution to *some* problems, but people who apply it to *every* problem (as the quote is talking about) soon find themselves in deep water.

Comment: @rmunn No, it’s really moronic. Here’s a better one (paraphrased from Stephan T Lavavej): “Even complex regular expressions are vastly simpler to write, debug and maintain than equivalent, hand-written parsers.” Sure, if you’re writing an HTML parser in regex you’re doing it wrong. But that’s a statement about *you*, not about regex.

Comment: I'd like to see even an expert like Lavavej write a regular expression that is easier to debug than a simple state-machine-based parser for some cases. For example, finding the matching close paren in `(text with "strings) and \"quotes in strings\")")` where you have to account for quotes and backslash escapes (not an uncommon parsing situation). The real right tool for that is a lexer, but the hand-written state-machine parser would be far simpler than the equivalent regex on this one. The jwz quote should not be *applied* moronically, but it is not itself moronic.

Comment: @rmunn Well that’s a perfect example of where not to use a regex, since the language you want to parse is simply not *regular*. Same as my HTML example. Nobody is arguing this point. But here you’re trying to use a hammer to screw in a screw. You *cannot* blame the hammer for failing, that’s simply nonsense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is redundant, and plain `\w` would work just as well. See https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

> `\d`
>
> When the `UNICODE` flag is not specified, matches any decimal digit; this is equivalent to the set `[0-9]`. With `UNICODE`, it will match whatever is classified as a decimal digit in the Unicode character properties database.
>
> `\w`
>
> When the `LOCALE` and `UNICODE` flags are not specified, matches any alphanumeric character and the underscore; this is equivalent to the set `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. With `LOCALE`, it will match the set `[0-9_]` plus whatever characters are defined as alphanumeric for the current locale. If `UNICODE` is set, this will match the characters `[0-9_]` plus whatever is classified as alphanumeric in the Unicode character properties database.

Comment: Why are you linking to Perl documentation for a Python question?

Comment: The first sentence of https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html specifically mentions Perl's regexes: 
This module provides regular expression matching operations similar to those found in Perl.

Comment: @davejagoda: No, they look similar, but they are not the same. Don't use reference for one language for another.